# Using raspberry pi to control 4 stepper motors

Tags: robotics, step-motor

For a hobby-project I would like to control 4 nema23 stepper motors for a Cartesian cnc-like setup using a raspberry pi.

According to this tutorial, it should work in principle using a TB6600 Motor driver:
https://danielwilczak101.medium.com/control-a-stepper-motor-using-python-and-a-raspberry-pi-11f67d5a8d6d

I would rather avoid using a controller board and have full control over the motors from code. My understanding is that these boards communicate using higher-level G-codes.

So my question is, would that work? What kind of power source would be necessary?

Comment: This might help, but you need to translate G-code to python: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135191/rpi-pico-micropythpn-controlling-tmc2208-tmc2209-tmc2225-stepper-motor-drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a stepper driver.  If you are calling the TB6600 board a controller board then you need it.  You need one per stepper.

The TB6600 board does not use G-code.

If you want to use G-code you will have to translate the G-code into the stepper movements required.  That is a difficult problem.  I'd say too difficult for a hobby project.

Comment: Thank you, yes I think you are right. I am probably better off just using a cnc controller board to handle the drivers.